# Windows XP - Black screen after boot logo

Tags: windows-xp, boot, chkdsk

When Windows XP boot screen finished, a black screen remains.

Now what I've tried:
Using the Windows XP disk and the console(<kbd>R</kbd>)-option.
Then there I started `chkdsk /r` and `fixboot` and `fixmbr`.

It all did not help. Someone mentioned to use `sfc /scannow` but the console says `Unknown command`. I tried to use it at `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`. The sfc.exe exists there but it doesn't use it.

Any other suggestions?  I've really tried a lot (including to look up similiar failures on superuser.com).

Comment: sfc /scannow is a Windows Vista+ only command

Comment: after black screen, can you hear it still continuing on? hard drive activity? In Safe Mode F8 it boots up with no black screen? Did you add new hard ware recently?

Comment: @Logman Nothing happens. Hard drive spins, does not stop. Safe mode also fails. Nothing added recently. I think repairing the Windows files might help. Any idea?   
@ Ramhound True, but the file exists. Thought it would be accessable on the console